# sum 30 rows but excluding some rows bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Look i have this table so i need to make a sum over of 30 days over every timday, but the problem is that there is some dates i need to exclude while i am doing the sum over, so i need a query where i  make that sum over, just as a example let say that i need to calculate the sum of 5 days but i need to exclude from 2023-12-30 to 2023-12-27, so the sum i expect to get is the sales of 2023-12-31, 2023-12-26, 2023-12-25, 2023-12-24, 2023-12-23, but for 2023-30, since is on the list to exclude, the window should be from 2023-12-26 to 2023-12-22 as so on

| SIT_SITE_ID | TIM_DAY | SAP_SKU | SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | '2023-12-31' | 3915 | 3 |
| M | '2023-12-30' | 3915 | 0 |
| M | '2023-12-29' | 3915 | 5 |
| M | '2023-12-28' | 3915 | 3 |
| M | '2023-12-27' | 3915 | 5 |
| M | '2023-12-26' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-25' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-24' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-23' | 3915 | 0 |
| M | '2023-12-22' | 3915 | 0 |
| M | '2023-12-21' | 3915 | 6 |
| M | '2023-12-20' | 3915 | 2 |
| M | '2023-12-19' | 3915 | 3 |
| M | '2023-12-18' | 3915 | 4 |
| M | '2023-12-17' | 3915 | 2 |
| M | '2023-12-16' | 3915 | 3 |
| M | '2023-12-15' | 3915 | 2 |
| M | '2023-12-14' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-13' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-12' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-11' | 3915 | 0 |
| M | '2023-12-10' | 3915 | 5 |
| M | '2023-12-09' | 3915 | 1 |
| M | '2023-12-09' | 3915 | 1 |

hopefully someone can help me and remember is on bigquery

i try this but it doesnot work on bigquey:

````sql
EXCLUSION_COUNT AS (
    SELECT
        SIT_SITE_ID,
        ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU,
        COUNT(DISTINCT TIM_DAY) AS exclusion_days
    FROM
        TABLA_AUX
    WHERE
        TIM_DAY IN (SELECT DISTINCT FECHA FROM SBOX_INSTOCK.FECHAS_T1_BOPS)
    GROUP BY
        SIT_SITE_ID,
        ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU
)
SELECT
    t1.SIT_SITE_ID,
    t1.TIM_DAY,
    t1.ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU,
    t1.SI,
    SUM(t1.SI) OVER (
        PARTITION BY t1.SIT_SITE_ID, t1.ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU 
        ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(t1.TIM_DAY) 
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND t2.exclusion_days PRECEDING
    ) AS ventas_30_dias
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        LAG(TIM_DAY, 29) OVER (PARTITION BY SIT_SITE_ID, ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU ORDER BY TIM_DAY) AS start_date
    FROM
        TABLA_AUX t
) t1
JOIN
    EXCLUSION_COUNT t2
ON
    t1.SIT_SITE_ID = t2.SIT_SITE_ID
    AND t1.ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU = t2.ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU
WHERE
    SAFE_CAST(t1.ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU AS INT64) = 39165 AND t1.SIT_SITE_ID = 'MLM'
ORDER BY
    t1.SIT_SITE_ID,
    t1.ITE_ITEM_SAP_SKU,
    t1.TIM_DAY DESC;```
````